# How do I get rid of windows on linux?

Tags: windows, delete

I have 2 operating systems, Windows and ubuntu. What should I do to eliminate windos operating system and make ubuntu system the only one?

Comment: Remove the windows partition, resize the linux partition(s).

Comment: Welcome, could you add an image of gparted showing the layout of the drive? [edit] the question  and use the image tool to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Stop GParted and reboot (Tap the power icon at the upper-right side of the screen and tap on Shut Down or Restart). Once you have booted back into the Ubuntu system installed on the hard drive, update your GRUB menu to exclude the Windows option, by running sudo update-grub in a Terminal window ( Ctrl + Alt + T ).

Comment: This will remove the boot option, but not free up the space.

Comment: I think you forgot the part about deleting the partition before you are done with gparted.